# Character encoding error, Chinese filenames mangled when downloaded via Firefox.

Tags: python, firefox

system info: `debian8` ,`firefox` version is the latest `55.0.3`.

Chinese character can be displayed in the right way on my system.
Some filenames are mangled when download. Content in the file is not affected. Let's take a concrete example.

No messy code for the webpage.
[origin webpage](https://wenku.baidu.com/view/15d2e847b14e852458fb5791.html)
[image]

To click the `下载`(download) button on the right corner.
Still no messy code for both filename and content in the web page.

[image]

To click the `下载`(download) button on the bottom.

[image]

The filename changed into messy code!
And all  content in the filename are no messy code!

[image]

It is no use to set the encoding in firefox as `unicdoe` or `chinese,simplified`.
It is no use to open my firefox with `env LANG=zh_CN.GBK firefox`.

In my example ,the filename is `2015ÄêµÚÆß°æ±±´óºËÐÄÆÚ¿¯Ä¿Â¼`.
1.How to set my os or firefox to solve the problem?
2.Is there a way to change `2015ÄêµÚÆß°æ±±´óºËÐÄÆÚ¿¯Ä¿Â¼` into `2015年第七版北大核心期刊目录`?

```
>>> str="2015Äê×îÐÂ2014°æ±±´óºËÐÄÆÚ¿¯Ä¿Â¼"
>>> str.encode("utf8")
b'2015\xc3\x84\xc3\xaa\xc3\x97\xc3\xae\xc3\x90\xc3\x822014\xc2\xb0\xc3\xa6\xc2\xb1\xc2\xb1\xc2\xb4\xc3\xb3\xc2\xba\xc3\x8b\xc3\x90\xc3\x84\xc3\x86\xc3\x9a\xc2\xbf\xc2\xaf\xc3\x84\xc2\xbf\xc3\x82\xc2\xbc'
>>> y=str.encode("utf8")
>>> print(y.decode("gbk"))
2015脛锚脳卯脨脗2014掳忙卤卤麓贸潞脣脨脛脝脷驴炉脛驴脗录
```

It should be `2015年第七版北大核心期刊目录` not `2015脛锚脳卯脨脗2014掳忙卤卤麓贸潞脣脨脛脝脷驴炉脛驴脗录`.

It has something to do with my os locale?

```
 locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

How to set the locale in order to display the  filename properly?

Comment: interesting, might this have something to do with your os language in language settings? because the problem as you show it appears at the download dialogue phase

Comment: It is a simple problem?Please show me your answer!!!

Comment: Have you tried to get the direct download url from Firefox and download it via wget or curl? If it shows your expectations, then it may be a issue of Firefox but system pref.

Comment: even if problem one sovled ,problem two remains,to change 2015ÄêµÚÆß°æ±±´óºËÐÄÆÚ¿¯Ä¿Â¼ into 2015年第七版北大核心期刊目录?

Comment: Could you sniff headers with which the file is transmitted?

Comment: What does this have to do with python?